# nasm and gcc: 32 bit linking failed (64 bit Mac OS X)

Tags: gcc, assembly, nasm, ld, i386

I've just compiled a assembley file with `nasm` this way:

```
$ nasm -f elf somefile.asm -o somefile.o
```

After that I want to link `somefile.o` to a programm with `gcc`

```
$ gcc -m32 somefile.o -o someprogramm
```

But linking the file prints the following error:

```
ld: warning: ignoring file somefile.o, file was built for unsupported file format which is 
not the architecture being linked (i386)
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_main", referenced from:
     start in crt1.10.6.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: can you post the somefile.asm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a time I decided  to use *Linux* for this kind of programms, because it has more flexibility. You can use Linux on a virtual machine like *Virtual Box*.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're having is that you're creating a 32-bit Linux(ELF) object file which isn't compatible with the Mac OS X object format. Try switching '-f elf' to '-f macho32'.