# How to run x86 .asm on macOS Sierra

Tags: macos, assembly

I have problem with compilation .asm file on macOS can somebody help me?

Here is my repository:
https://github.com/ondrej-111/Asm.git

I tried to compile it with this commands:

> nasm -f elf -d macho64 asm_io.asm
>
> nasm -f elf prvy.asm
>
> gcc -c driver.c
>
> gcc -o prvy driver.o prvy.o asm_io.o

but I always get the same error:

> ld: warning: ld: warning: ignoring file asm_io.o, file was built for
>   unsupported file format ( 0x7F 0x45 0x4C 0x46 0x01 0x01 0x01 0x00 0x00
>   0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 ) which is not the architecture
>   being linked (x86_64): asm_io.oignoring file prvy.o, file was built
>   for unsupported file format ( 0x7F 0x45 0x4C 0x46 0x01 0x01 0x01 0x00
>   0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 ) which is not the
>   architecture being linked (x86_64): prvy.o
>
> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:   "_asm_main", referenced
>   from:
>         _main in driver.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to
>   see invocation)

I searched some similar issues but any one helped me to fix it.( I tried this - [How can I run this assembly code on OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18689404/how-can-i-run-this-assembly-code-on-os-x))

Comment: macos doesn't use elf format.  Try `nasm -f macho64` instead.

Comment: @Jester since that is the correct answer, please write it as an answer.

Comment: At first I tried nasm -f macho64 wih asm_io.asm and prvy.asm but there was error about instructions not supported in 64-bit mode so then I tried use macho32 flag it worked but after last command(gcc -o prvy driver.o prvy.o asm_io.o) I get error again...
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  **"_asm_main",= I think that here is the problem with underscope**;
referenced from:
      _main in driver.o

Comment: Another one question: is there some easier way to run this project? Maybe install some distribution of Linux or Windows on VM.